# Error conn fetch_assoc MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, poo

acudo a ustedes dado que estoy estancado en una función de MySQLi orientado a objetos.

Intento obtener el ID (A_i) de los tokens correspondientes de los usuarios, en una tabla llamada Tokens. El problema es que no da errores y además me devuelve un resultado vacío.

Aclaro que el token que utilizo para testear el código es exactamente el mismo que está en la tabla, ya que básicamente copio y pego el mismo, por lo cual no es problema de inexistencia del mismo.

Quisiera saber qué estoy haciendo mal, porque estoy estancado desde hace 1 semana exactamente. Gracias de antemano.

Les dejo el código:

**modules/config.php**

```
<?php

    $host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "123456";
    $database = "database";

    $db = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_pass, $database);

?>
```

**classes/token.php**

```
<?php

    class Token
    {
        function usuarioToken($token)
        {
            include("../modules/config.php");

            // Seleccion de datos segun token
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tokens` WHERE `token`='".$token."'";
            $db->query($sql);
            $buffer = [];
            while ($data = $db->fetch_assoc) {
                $buffer[] = $data["id"];
            }
            return $buffer;
        }
    }

?>
```

**verify/index.php**

```
<?php

    include("../classes/token.php");

    $token = new Token();

    print_r( $token->usuarioToken($_GET["t"]) );

?>
```

**Resultado obtenido...**

```
Array ( )
```

Comment: Ya probaste a ejecutar la consulta directamente en la consola de SQL ?

Comment: Primer error a corregir. Estás omitiendo los `()` al llamar a `fetch_assoc()`... Corrige: **`while ($data = $db->fetch_assoc()) {`**

Comment: Camilo Vasquez:

La consulta SQL desde la consola funciona lo más bien.
Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0004 seconds.)
SELECT `id` FROM `tokens` WHERE `token`='8owrusgg15mlh1pzdklgfhr36h7ahtbg7xxsg4z80bj73zx799'

Comment: A. Cedano: Si pongo los (), no funciona, me da el siguiente error... "Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_assoc() in /home/propiya/public_html/newsite/classes/token.php on line 53".

Comment: ¿Quéeee? Pero si ese es un método de mysqli, [míralo aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) ¿`$db` es una instancia de conexión de mysqli o es una clase que te has creado tú mismo con sus propios métodos? ¿O acaso estás usando PDO y no mysqli?

Comment: `$db` es esto `$db = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_pass, $database);`, que de hecho acabo de agregarlo en la pregunta (está en el archivo de config.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya vi tu error.

Estás actuando sobre `$db` en el fetch, y debes actuar sobre los resultados devueltos.

```
class Token
{
    function usuarioToken($token)
    {
        include("../modules/config.php");

        // Seleccion de datos segun token
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tokens` WHERE `token`='".$token."'";
        $resultado=$db->query($sql); //Resultado de la consulta
        $buffer = [];
        while ($data = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { //con ()
            $buffer[] = $data["id"];
        }
        return $buffer;
    }
}
```

> Nota:
>
> Se recomienda el uso de consultas preparadas para dar seguridad a tus
>   BD.

Escribiré aquí el código usando consultas preparadas y evaluando los posibles errores:

```
class Token
{
    function usuarioToken($token)
    {
        include("../modules/config.php");

        if ($db)
        {

            // Seleccion de datos segun token
            $sql = "SELECT id FROM `tokens` WHERE `token`=?";  //Parece que sólo quieres el id

            $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);

            if ($stmt){
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $token);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $resultado=$db->query($sql); //Resultado de la consulta
            $buffer = [];
            while ($data = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { //con ()
                $buffer[] = $data["id"];
            }

            return $buffer;
            $stmt->close();

            }else{

                echo "Error preparando la consulta";

            }

        //Cerrar $db si es preciso

        }else{

            echo "Error en la conexión";

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Ahora entiendo por qué no me daba los resultados. Me había olvidado de almacenar los resultados y por éso no me dejaba usar los () en el fetch_assoc. Muchísimas gracias, lo voy a tener en cuenta a futuro. Te ganaste mi voto.

Comment: @Skollprog con eso debería resolverse el problema. Por favor cuando puedas lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien constesta a mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Saludos.